# PHP: How to change variable value to another class

Tags: php

I'm creating a class that uses google.

I want to return the value as an object from another class.

Example:

```
$x = new SocialServices($key, $keySecret, $apiKey);
```

Here I call the `Google()` method which requires a `google.php` file and creates the new object

```
$x->Google();
```

Here I want return Google class as `$this`.

```
    public function Google() {
        require 'PHP/google.php';
        new Google($this->key, $this->secret, $this->apiKey, "#Google");
    }
```

When i call

```
$x->YouTube();
```

It will be works.

Comment: Tried to improve the wording, at least according to I interpreted the question

Comment: Thank you man...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understood what you're asking, but I know for sure that you are missing a `return` in your method.

That means that the working method that returns a `Google` object would be

```php
public function Google() {
    require 'PHP/google.php';
    return new Google($this->key, $this->secret, $this->apiKey, "#Google");
}
```

What I don't understand is what you mean by "Here I want return Google class as `$this`". I you want the method to return the same object to be able to concatenate, you can assign the `Google` object to an internal variable declared in the constructor and then just return `$this` right after the assignment.

By the way I would suggest you to avoid using the `require`, it's better if you use composer's autoloading.

Comment: I tested but user must make $x = $x->Google(); but i want when user makes $x->Google(); $x = a Google class but not SocialServices();

Comment: @MDReal That's exactly what happens if you return the `Google` object as in my example, if you  overwrite the value of `$x` with `$x->Google()` it will then be a `Google` object.